# How to detect if file is an image in perl

Tags: image, perl, detection

In order to set some varaibles i need the information if a given file on my server is an image. I do not know anything about the file exept for its location and name.

**Is there a way to detect if a file is an image WITHOUT looking at the file extension?**

Comment: I suppose you can detect some formats of image (.jpg, .png, .gif), but not all existing formats. ) Would it be sufficient?

Comment: my question was aiming for a solution WITHOUT looking at the file extensions

Comment: What made you think I talked about the file extensions, not the file formats?

Comment: @raina77ow: well, this might be sufficient. could you provide some code?

Comment: On Unix/Linux there is the `file` command that makes canonical "magic" tests of a file.  I don't know what you might need on non-Unix/Linux platforms.

Answer (score 11, accepted):

An easy way to do this is to delegate the work to ImageMagick through the [PerlMagick](http://search.cpan.org/dist/PerlMagick/) CPAN module. The `Identify` and `Ping` methods are designed for that purpose.

```
use strict;
use Image::Magick;

my $im = Image::Magick->new();

my ($width, $height, $size, $format) = $im->Ping('/path/to/my/image.jpg');
```

After executing this little program, the `$format` variable will contain a string with the identified format of the image (in this example: "JPEG"), or `undef` in case of error (non-existing file, unrecognized format, etc.).

**Edit:** ...and to completely answer your question: it is probably safe to assume that a given file is an image if `Ping` returns a format string, and if it is part of whichever subset you decide to white-list from ImageMagick's [list of supported formats](http://www.imagemagick.org/script/formats.php) (which also includes non-image formats).

Answer (score 7):

JRFerguson mentions the command `file` in a comment attached to the question. It comes with a C library counter-part, `libmagic`. The Perl binding is called [File::LibMagic](http://p3rl.org/File::LibMagic).

```
use File::LibMagic qw();
my $detect = File::LibMagic->new;
$detect->checktype_filename("first_success.jpg") =~ /^image/
```

Expression returns true for image types.

Comment: Another comparable module I have used is [`File::MimeInfo::Magic`](https://metacpan.org/module/File::MimeInfo::Magic)

Comment: The FDO magic file sucks. As of v0.91 of `shared-mime-info`, there are only 377 recognised types, `file` 5.11 has over five times as many.

Answer (score 3):

The command `file`, as first mentioned by @JRFerguson, has limitations versus `File::LibMagic`, `Image::Magick`, or `Image::ExifTool`.

But `file` is great when you can't install or use those modules. As for sample code, you could go with something like this:

```
my $file = "/dir/images/image.jpg";
my $type = `file $file`;

unless ($type =~ /JPEG/i
     || $type =~ /PNG/i) {
print "The file is not a valid JPEG or PNG.";
}
```

The idea is just to regex against the known image formats.

Answer (score 1):

You got two good answers already. There's one more tool that can be valuable in these cases. It's going to be slower than the libmagic solutions but it's sometimes preferable for the additional information and utility. I do not know which tool is more comprehensive or likely to fail on edge cases. [Image::ExifTool](https://metacpan.org/module/Image%3a%3aExifTool)–

```
use Image::ExifTool "ImageInfo";

my $info = ImageInfo(shift || die "Give an image file!\n");

print "This is a ", $info->{FileType}, "\n";

use Data::Dump "pp";
print "Here's more...\n";
pp $info;
```

Answer (score 1):

Here is one of the ways I did it. Using the perl module form CPAN "Image-Size-3.300 > Image::Size". it also has file attributes image "type". You can then take these variables and use the information to process the code for your application.

```
#!/usr/bin/perl 

use Image::Size;

print "Content-type: text/html\n\n";

my ($image_width, $image_height, $image_type) = imgsize("path/image.jpg");

unless ($image_type =~ /JPG/i
 || $image_type =~ /PNG/i) {
print "The file is not a valid JPG or PNG.";
}

#To see the results printed to the web browser
 print "<br>(image.jpg) $image_width - $image_height - $image_type<br>\n";

exit(0);
```